# Existence, Uniqueness, and Boundedness of Solutions to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the initial value problem

$$y'=A(t)y+g(t)$$

where the $n$ x $n$ matrix $A(t)$ and the $n$ column vector $g(t)$ are continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and are such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [|A(s)|+|g(s)|]ds < \infty$$

Prove that the initial value problem for any given $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ possesses a unique solution $y(t)$ on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and that $|y(t)|$ is bounded on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Once we've determined the existence of the unique solution, I think the boundedness may not be so complicated to prove.  I'm not really sure where to start with proving the existence of the solution though.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [|A(s)|+|g(s)|]ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |A(s)|ds + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g(s)|ds< \infty$$

So each of the individual norms $|A(t)|$ and $|g(t)|$ is bounded, which I believe also implies that the limit (as $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$) of each norm is zero (please correct me if I'm wrong here).  I think this would then imply that $|A(t)|+|g(t)|$ is Lipschitz on any closed, bounded subset of $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Any thoughts, hints, or proofs would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Once you know that it's Lipschitz what do you know about the mapping? What can you say it does to the "distance" between two vectors?

Comment: I suppose I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at. A Lipschitz function is one whose slope is essentially bounded, so this would imply that there is also a bound on the difference between the slopes of any two tangents to a given solution curve.